# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.Double when running openjdk

Tags: eclipse, double, java, nosuchmethoderror

I have written a command line app in java. It works perfectly in eclipse, exported to jar works in newest java on windows, but crashes at some point on ubuntu server 12.04 `openjdk-7-jre-headless`.

```
java version "1.7.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.3) (7u91-2.6.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 24.91-b01, mixed mode, sharing)
```

There seems to be some problem with Double.min function:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.Double.min(DD)D
    at Test.main(Test.java:149)
    ... 5 more
```

And here is the problematic code:

```
String balance = "25000.00"
double MAX = 20000;
String amount = Double.toString(Double.min(MAX, Double.parseDouble(balance)));
```

I tried to compile it to different version of java 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8 and error remains the same.

**SOLUTION**

```
String amount = Double.toString(Math.min(MAX, Double.parseDouble(balance)));
```

As per all excellent answers, Double.min is not available before java 8. However there is Math.min function doing exactly the same from java 6.

Comment: Double.min was added in Java 8, so make sure you are actually compiling in Java 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [javadocs](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/Double.java#Double.min%28double%2Cdouble%29), `min` method in `Double` was added only in JDK 8.

You should make sure you are running your code against JDK8. Also if you want to use JDK below v8, then consider using Math's [min](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Math.java#Math.min%28double%2Cdouble%29) method.

Comment: As per your answer, I changed Double.min() into Math.min(). It works now.

Answer (score 2):

[`Double#min(double, double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#min-double-double-) was introduces in Java 8, which you compiled your code with. When you try **running it** with an older JDK this method cannot be found (as it wasn't introduced yet), and you get the error you mentioned.

You should either make sure you're using Java 8's JDK or change your code to not rely on this method. E.g., by creating your own `min` method:

```
public static double min (double a, double b) {
    return a < b ? a : b;
}
```